# POSTGRES SUM big someSting::decimal

Tags: postgresql

I try to SUM and cast at the same time. I have a column with big numbers with a lot of decimals for example: "0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000043232137067129047"

when I try `sum(amount::decimal)`  I get the following error message `org.jkiss.dbeaver.model.sql.DBSQLException: SQL Error [22003]: ERROR: value overflows numeric format Where: parallel worker`

What I don't get is that the doc is saying ***up to 131072 digits before the decimal point; up to 16383 digits after the decimal point***
And my longest casted string is 63 digits so I don't get it.

What am I missing and how could I make my sum ?

EDIT:

amount type is varchar(255)

EDIT2:
I found out it's only when I try to CREATE a table from this request that it breaks, request is working fine in itself, how can it be due to create table ?

Complete request:

```
 create table cross_dapp_ft as (select sender,receiver,sum(amount::decimal),contract from ft_transfer_event ftce 
 where receiver in (
      select account_id from batch.cc cc
      where classification not in ('ft')
)
group by sender,receiver,contract);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248621/discussion-on-question-by-francois-richard-postgres-sum-big-somestingdecimal).

Answer (score 0):

As Samuel Liew suggested in the comments, some rows where corrupted. Conclusion is , to be safe don't store numbers as string.